# How is a component event caught by a component listener

Tags: java, swing, listener

This is the method to catch specify component events:

```
public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
    displayMessage(e.getComponent().getClass().getName() + " --- Hidden");
}
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    displayMessage(e.getComponent().getClass().getName() + " --- Moved");
}
```

when I changed the size of a frame or moved it, the corresponding method is invoked. I do not see any specific code that say something like if frame move, listener invoke componentHidden; or if frame is resized, invoke componentMoved. So, how can the listener classify component events when it catch them, so that corresponding methods are invoked?

Comment: The code is being called by the Swing library. You will want to look in the Swing source code and where you'll find this hidden code.

Comment: The key is in understanding the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) since this is how all Swing listeners work, and is a general design principle that is quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into any source code, the basic event handling model, for the most part, goes something like this:

You have a component. The component has some state.

```
private boolean pressed;
```

When the state changes, an event will be fired.

```
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    fireButtonPressed();
}

protected void fireButtonPressed() {
    performAction(new MyButtonEvent(name));
}
```

You can add listeners/handlers that "listen" for this event

```
private List<MyButtonListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

public void addMyButtonListener(MyButtonListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```

And they will perform the callback, when passed this event

```
protected void performAction(MyButtonEvent event) {
    for (MyButtonListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.doButtonAction(event);   // doButtonAction === callback
    }
}
```

Here are the basic classes used (without a GUI, just a simple console app example)

**MyButton**

```
public class MyButton {

    private List<MyButtonListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean pressed;
    private String name;

    public MyButton(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        fireButtonPressed();
    }

    protected void fireButtonPressed() {
        performAction(new MyButtonEvent(name));
    }

    public void addMyButtonListener(MyButtonListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    protected void performAction(MyButtonEvent event) {
        for (MyButtonListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.doButtonAction(event);
        }
    }
}
```

**MYButtonListener**

```
public interface MyButtonListener {
    public void doButtonAction(MyButtonEvent event);
}
```

**MyButtonEvent**

```
public class MyButtonEvent {
    private String name;

    public MyButtonEvent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyButtonListener listener = new MyButtonListener() {
            @Override
            public void doButtonAction(MyButtonEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getName() + " pressed");
            }  
        };
        MyButton button = new MyButton("Hello Button");
        button.addMyButtonListener(listener);

        // change button state to cause event to be fired
        button.setPressed(true);
    }
}
```

This is an overly simplified example, but still demonstrates the basic point. In a GUI, the pressing of the button will cause the `pressed` state to change, and a similar chain of events as demonstrated above will occur.

Same thing in your particular question. The frame state is changed, and all the ComponentListeners you add to it, will get their methods called, getting passed a `ComponentEvent`. Depending on which state changes, that will be the callback method called. Again, without looking at any source code, in psuedocode, something like:

```
for (ComponentListener listener : componentListeners) {
    if (changedState == Component.MOVED) {
        listener.componentMoved(componentEvent);
    }
}
```